# Como usar el permiso "Draw over othre apps" para obtener esta informacion

Tags: java, android, kotlin

quería saber como hacen las aplicaciones como pokegenie o calcy iv para obtener datos del pokemon go, he buscado por google y noo encuentro como hacerlo, solo que tengo que usar el "Draw over other apps"

[image: Imágen de prueba]

La idea es desde una app con un botón flotante siempre delante del juego, poder extraer el CP, el nivel de la barra blanca(arco blanco), el nombre del pokémon y las barras naranjas.

Comment: El permiso `DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APPS` lo que te permite es poner el botón flotante frente a las aplicación, luego aplicaciones como `calcy iv ` lo que hacen es tomar una captura de la pantalla y con esa imagen extraer los datos que necesitan, ya que PokemonGo como tal no provee esos datos, he ahí el merito de estas aplicaciones.

Comment: Y como sacan captura, porque yo la saco y solo consigo una captura del botón, tengo que iniciar el juego desde la propia app?